# 2 condition in pandas dataFrame indexes

Tags: python, pandas

I have this rows filtering:

```
idx = dataset.data.groupby(['a', 'b'])['c'].transform(max) == dataset.data['c']
dataset.data = dataset.data[idx]
```

For this dataset:

```
a | b | c | d
0 | 0 | 1 | True
0 | 0 | 2 | True
0 | 1 | 3 | True
0 | 2 | 4 | False
0 | 2 | 5 | False
```

I'll get:

```
a | b | c | d
0 | 0 | 1 | True
0 | 1 | 3 | True
0 | 2 | 5 | False
```

I want to add for this condition that removes only rows that their field 'd' is false, so in the above example I'll get:

```
a | b | c | d
0 | 0 | 1 | True
0 | 0 | 2 | True
0 | 1 | 3 | True
0 | 2 | 5 | False
```

Can someone help me add it, please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, keep rows where `'c'` is the `max` **or** `d` is `True`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    'b': [0, 0, 1, 2, 2],
    'c': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'd': [True, True, True, False, False]
})

# Max value of C
c1 = df.groupby(['a', 'b'])['c'].transform(max) == df['c']
# D is True
c2 = df.d
# Or together
idx = c1 | c2

print(df[idx])
```

`df[idx]`:

```
   a  b  c      d
0  0  0  1   True
1  0  0  2   True
2  0  1  3   True
4  0  2  5  False
```

---

The one-liner:

```
df[df.groupby(['a', 'b'])['c'].transform(max).eq(df['c']) | df['d']]
```

Comment: bit simplier in one line i think `df.loc[df.groupby(['a','b'])['c'].transform('max').eq(df['c']) | df['d'].ne(False)]`

Comment: @Umar.H I'm always torn with one-liners. It's very easy to forget some parenthesis or obfuscate the actual reason for certain conditions when all together. Also from a learning standpoint it can be tricky to understand. Regardless I've updated my answer to include the one-line option as well. =)